# Need ng-pattern for universal number

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working on an Application,

I need to apply validation for phone number in ng-pattern
I have used ng-pattern="/^(?(\d{3}))?[ .-]?(\d{3})[ .-]?(\d{4})$/"

Which is not accepting universal phone number.

Can any one guide me which is the right expression for universal phone number like below examples.

(123)-456-7899

123-456-7899

Comment: For testing regluar expressions fast and easy, try this site: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

US nunbers: ^(+\d{1,2}\s)?(?\d{3})?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$

Non US numbers: ^(+\d{1,2}\s)?(?\d{3})?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$